# Update values without deleting others and remove existing ones in column PHP CONCAT

Tags: php, mysql, select, sql-update, concatenation

I have multiple select option box which changing "about_demographics" in MySQL.

**Example:**

In `about_demographics` I have values: `g01,g02,g03,`

And if I try to update these values by select box and I selected `g02,g03,g05,` and deselected `g01,` then value is `g01,g02,g03,g02,g03,g05,`

**What I expect:**

In `about_demographics` I have values: `g01,g02,g03,`

And if I try to update these values by select box and I selected `g02,g03,g05,` and deselected `g01,` then value is `g02,g03,g05,`

```
<select name="work[]" multiple>
  <option value="g01">1</option>
  <option value="g02">2</option>
  <option value="g03">3</option>
  <option value="g04">4</option>
  <option value="g05">5</option>
</select>

<?php
  $work_array = array('g01', 'g02', 'g03', 'g04', 'g05');
  foreach ($work_array as $a_work) {
    if (in_array($a_work, $_POST['work'])) {
      $first_part_all.=$a_work.",";
    }
  }

  $db->Query("UPDATE user_about SET about_demographics = CONCAT(about_demographics, 
  '$first_part_all') WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
?>
```

Comment: So you're having problems with duplicated values?

Comment: @ggderas Yes. This is full code how it works https://pastebin.com/sDQ0nAAv.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is because you are appending the pre-existing `$first_part_all` variable without removing the previous values.  You should be able to both fix this and eliminate the need for the loop by using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
<select name="work[]" multiple>
  <option value="g01">1</option>
  <option value="g02">2</option>
  <option value="g03">3</option>
  <option value="g04">4</option>
  <option value="g05">5</option>
</select>

<?php
$db->Query("UPDATE user_about SET about_demographics = CONCAT(about_demographics, 
  '".implode(",",$_POST['work'])."') WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
?>
```

**EDIT:** This alternative would still require a loop, but it would clear your `$first_part_all` variable at the beginning and require little change to the existing code to produce the expected results:

```
<select name="work[]" multiple>
  <option value="g01">1</option>
  <option value="g02">2</option>
  <option value="g03">3</option>
  <option value="g04">4</option>
  <option value="g05">5</option>
</select>

<?php
  $work_array = array('g01', 'g02', 'g03', 'g04', 'g05');
  $first_part_all = '';
  foreach ($work_array as $a_work) {
    if (in_array($a_work, $_POST['work'])) {
      $first_part_all.=$a_work.",";
    }
  }

  $db->Query("UPDATE user_about SET about_demographics = CONCAT(about_demographics, 
  '$first_part_all') WHERE id = '".$data['id']."'");
?>
```

Comment: @AdamNickens - You could alternatively add `$first_part_all = '';` to the beginning of your php, and that should work without changing any of your code

Comment: Is it possible to use "$first_part_all" inside UPDATE? Because I minified code above. This is full code: https://pastebin.com/sDQ0nAAv.